# Duplicate output in MPIEXEC

Tags: cluster

I have installed MPI on my 3 node raspberry-pi 3B+ cluster and whenever I run any command I get 12 replies, 4 from each node, as an example, when I run `mpirun -machinefile machine-file hostname` I get the output

```
pi0
pi0
pi0
pi0
pi1
pi1
pi1
pi1
pi2
pi2
pi2
pi2
```

can anyone tell me what may be causing this and/or how to fix it?